# is there an event fired when accuracy of position changes in google maps android?

Tags: events, gps, maps

I would like to implement an "around me" app in Android based on mapview (min sdk version 10).

To give a good precision to the user, my idea is to open the mapview with enableMylocation setted, wait until the precision of gps is enough accurate (i.e. < 50 meters) and THEN ask to the db the Points Of Intenrest in a radius of 500 meters.

When mapview starts, the current position in newer enought accurate. the radius of the blue circle is often > 1000 meters. Is there a way, an event, to know when the accuracy changes? And what shoud be tested to know the new accuracy?

thank You very much!

Answer (score 0):

solved!
it is easy.
The first step: the activity must extends MapActivity  and implements LocationListener

2nd step:  in the onCreate method is necessary to create a location manager:   locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

3rd step: in the overrided method  onLocationChanged(Location location) you can test location.getAccuracy() and decide what accuracy you need..

4rth step: remember to put in the **onResume method**
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);
 and
locationManager.removeUpdates(this); 
in the **onPause** method!

that's all!!